# iOS Passbook Serial Number: What characters are valid? What is the max length?

Tags: ios, passbook

Passbook for iOS uses a serial number that your servers can use to identify a specific pass.

Does anyone know what characters are valid in the passbook serial number?  I know that digits and letters are valid, but are symbols/punctuation valid as well (e.g. "-" and ".")?

Also what is the maximum length of a serial number?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty much any character can be used, including '-' and '.', as long as the serial remains unique. Special characters,  like '\' will need to be properly escaped, although these may not be compatible with your database, or may cause other problems if not handled properly elsewhere in your code.

I have just tried a pass with the following serial and it added to Passbook with no problems.

```
"serialNumber":"[]{}-_)(*&^%$#@!`~+=|\\\/?.><,:;"
```

UTF8 encoded characters are also fine:

```
"serialNumber":"\u9127\u6a02\u611a" // Chinese characters 鄧樂愚
```

As for maximum length, I'm not aware of any limit, although it would be quite simple to experiment.

This serial of 400 characters also ingests ok.

```
"serialNumber":"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
```

I would recommend against using any sort of user input for the serial, since this may lead to non-unique collisions and open you up to injection attacks. Also adhering to XML standards is not a bad practice to avoid any problems if you change your architecture (say to a web service solution like AWS DynamoDB) down the line. Base64 encoding your serial would ensure widespread compatibility.

The serial can also be used to store metadata in the pass E.g.

```
"serialNumber":"UniqueID|data1|data2|data3|etc."
```

Comment: Thanks!  That covers all of the bases for me (a 400 character length is more than enough for my purchases).  I'm not sure this was down voted.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @DuneBug - the score is currently +4 -1, once you have more than 1k reputation, you can split scores into + and - votes